# python-escpos always show "Could not set configuration: [Errno 16] Resource busy"

Tags: python, printing

When I use python-escpos in my raspberry(modle B,use debian jessie),like this

```
>>> from escpos.printer import Usb
>>> pt = Usb(0x6868, 0x0500, 0, out_ep=0x3)
```

it shows:
**Could not set configuration: [Errno 16] Resource busy**

why?

I've already set udev rules, install libusb.....

here is my usb-print usb inf:

```
> DEVICE ID 6868:0500 on Bus 001 Address 004 =================  bLength 
> :   0x12 (18 bytes)  bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device  bcdUSB   
> :  0x200 USB 2.0  bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at
> interface  bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0  bDeviceProtocol        :  
> 0x0  bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)  idVendor             
> : 0x6868  idProduct              : 0x0500  bcdDevice              : 
> 0x100 Device 1.0  iManufacturer          :    0x1 Gprinter  iProduct  
> :    0x2 GP-58  iSerialNumber          :    0x3 6B728E8F3431 
> bNumConfigurations     :    0x1   CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA
> ==================================    bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)    bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration    wTotalLength 
> :   0x37 (55 bytes)    bNumInterfaces       :    0x2   
> bConfigurationValue  :    0x1    iConfiguration       :    0x0   
> bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered    bMaxPower            :  
> 0x32 (100 mA)
>     INTERFACE 0: Printer ===================================
>      bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
>      bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
>      bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
>      bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
>      bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
>      bInterfaceClass    :    0x7 Printer
>      bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
>      bInterfaceProtocol :    0x2
>      iInterface         :    0x0
>       ENDPOINT 0x84: Bulk IN ===============================
>        bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
>        bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
>        bEndpointAddress :   0x84 IN
>        bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
>        wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
>        bInterval        :    0xa
>       ENDPOINT 0x3: Bulk OUT ===============================
>        bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
>        bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
>        bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
>        bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
>        wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
>        bInterval        :    0xa
>     INTERFACE 1: Mass Storage ==============================
>      bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
>      bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
>      bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
>      bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
>      bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
>      bInterfaceClass    :    0x8 Mass Storage
>      bInterfaceSubClass :    0x6
>      bInterfaceProtocol :   0x50
>      iInterface         :    0x4 GP-58
>       ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
>        bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
>        bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
>        bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
>        bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
>        wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
>        bInterval        :    0x0
>       ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
>        bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
>        bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
>        bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
>        bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
>        wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
>        bInterval        :    0x0
```

thinks.

Comment: I get it! Because I use a GP-2102TF thermal-printer, It has Label/Receipt Mode, when printer's mode is Label Mode ,it can't use ESCPOS. To change mode,u can press 2 buttons when power on.